# Blueimp plugin fileupload Jquery: Send additional information to PHP handler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to send information (additional Handling form data) from fileupload jquery plugin (blueimp) to PHP file. In the PHP file handle can not get the information (content of variable). I think I have a problem in the code. Can some altruistic soul enlighten the way? Thanks in advance.

Javascript file:

```
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',   
    formData: {idGrupo: 250},  <----I want to send this to PHP file!
    done: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
       // $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('body');
   });
}
});
});
```

PHP file (index.php ):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler
{
    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        $sesionIdGrupo2 = $_REQUEST['idGrupo'];
}

    protected function trim_file_name($name, $type, $sesionIdGrupo2) {
        $name = parent::trim_file_name($name, $type);
        $name = $seionIdGrupo2;
        return $name;
}
}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler();
```

Again I appreciate the help, that would not do without this community (well yes, would do anything that was not code ;). Please be patient, I am newbie :(

Note: 
The variable $sesionIdGrupo2 not retrieve the value. My intention is to put the contents of this variable (250) as the name of the uploaded file. ¿Could it be a problem of global variables?

Answer (score 0):

To send Data to PHP UploadHandler.php just send it via url like this:

```
$(function () {
     $('#fileupload').fileupload({
          url: 'server/php/index.php?idGrupo=250',
          dataType: 'json',
          autoUpload: false,
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll try this solution to see if I served, and then comment the results. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

....i solve that problem! ...i put the Request inside the function "trim_file_name". I think is bad idea, but seem work...

```
protected function trim_file_name($name, $type) {
    $name = parent::trim_file_name($name, $type);
    $sesionIdGrupo = $_REQUEST['idGrupo']; <------this work, recibed 250
    $name = $sesionIdGrupo;
    return $name;
```

Saludos!